# Outlook contextual add-ins - download links are not working

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have contextual add-ins and when we click on highlighted text it will open a modal dialog, inside that it contains some link which can be downloaded. when we click on that link in web browser it works fine but when we tried on desktop outlook(Native) it is crashing.

[image]

In html i tried in 2 ways, one using anchor tag (<a href="" ng-href="api/rest/download....") and another using by blob (rest call) via angularjs.

Both ways are not working. Is this a limitation in Native outlook to not download any files or am i missing anything here?

Tried target=_blank and the result was same.

Comment: is the download from the same domain the add-in is running on? also, from what I understand, if you need to open any link, you need to use the displayDialogAsync API

Answer (score 0):

The contextual add-in dialog / card is not modal. It is transient dialog that gets closed when it loses focus. Clicking on a link to download a file will cause the dialog to lose focus and close. Also, to download a file, try the [openBrowserWindow API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/open-browser-window-api-requirement-sets). This will also close the contextual card.